# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un Snackbar en la versión 23?

Tags: android

Intento añadir un Snackbar pero no me lo reconoce, este es mi código.

```
btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logeado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Snackbar.make(v, "Logeado", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Mi gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ruben.red1"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ruben.red1"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Con la versión 23 no reconoce Snackbar :(.

Mil gracias

Comment: que version tiene el dispositivo donde lo estas probando?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que añadir la dependencia a la librería de `Design` en tu fichero `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    //Resto de tus dependencias
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No es suficiente con cambiar tu `compileSdkVersion` a una versión 23+, es necesario añadir la referencia de la [librería de compatibilidad de diseño](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design) dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

esta librería contiene ademas de snackbar,  navigation drawers, botón flotante y tabs.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]